How to translate the fork keyword from straight.el to a melpa recipe?
Given the straight.el snippet below, I'm unable to make sense of the fork keyword in context of the melpa manual.
How should I translate this snippet in order to use-package install it, without straight?
;; straight.el
(use-package foopackage
  :defer t
  :after some-package
  :straight (
             :host github
             :repo "user/repo"
             :fork "foobar")
  )


The point of the :fork  keyword is to load from a different repo that is not in melpa - so will not be in the melpa manual

I suggest doing M-: (info "(emacs) Fetching Package Sources") and M-: (info "(use-package) Install package") and see if package-vc can help you here.
